# Update a table from a join with another query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a tables 'players' and 'awards'. I have some duplicate player entries that have different id's but the same information otherwise.

I'm trying to update the awards that are associated with the second player entries, so that I can eventually remove the duplicates.

This obviously isn't the most efficient query, but it only needs to run once, and there are only 10-15 duplicates.
So far I have this:

```
UPDATE aw
SET aw.player_id = map.id1
FROM awards as aw,
    (SELECT a.id as id1, b.id as id2
    FROM players a, players b
    WHERE a.first_name = b.first_name 
    AND a.last_name = b.last_name 
    AND a.id != b.id 
    AND a.team is not null 
    AND a.college is not null) as map
WHERE map.id2 = aw.player_id
```

This gives me an unspecified syntax error, but if I replace the first two lines with just
"Select aw.player_id, map.id1", it returns a two column table with the expected values (so the column name and table references are all correct).

I must be missing something obvious, but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no FROM in [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

You should define tables in UPDATE section, before SET

```
UPDATE awards as aw,
  (SELECT a.id as id1, b.id as id2
  FROM players a, players b
  WHERE a.first_name = b.first_name 
  AND a.last_name = b.last_name 
  AND a.id != b.id 
  AND a.team is not null 
  AND a.college is not null) as map
SET aw.player_id = map.id1
WHERE map.id2 = aw.player_id
```

Comment: ahhh thank you so much. I knew it was something silly. My inexperience with sql is clearly showing!

Answer (score 0):

This should be syntactically correct. However, I'm not really sure it doeas what you want. **Test on staging data first!**

```
UPDATE
  players AS a 
INNER JOIN
  players AS b
ON
  a.first_name = b.first_name
  AND a.last_name = b.last_naem
  AND a.id != b.id
  AND a.team IS NOT NULL
  AND a.college IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN
  awards AS aw
ON
  b.id = aw.player_id
SET
  aw.player_id = a.id
```